# one profile2 profile for 2 users

Tags: 7, users

I'm working on a website for the elemantary school of my kids.
The parents should have the option to login to the site to consult information (children in classes, addresses of other parents,...).

Currently I've created one 'family' user account where the additional information (second parent, children, class, addresses) is stored in profile2. The problem is that when the parents are divorced the second parent should have also a user account (with a different password) but the profile2 information should be the same. So I need two user accounts with the same profile2 info.

How can I manage this in Drupal?

Thanx!

Jan

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if using Profile2 is the best in this case. It is really meant for storing profile information of a particular user (1 to 1 relationship). You could probably override this through a custom module, but that would be hackish. Can you migrate everything to a separate entity, even a node? In that case management would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I'd suggest using [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) or the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

Both modules allow grouping users / content. So each family could be a group with the parents / kids as members. Address information would be stored using a common group page, while the parents could still have different profiles.

In a later stage of your site you could also create groups containing all kids of a class and so on.

Comment: Since I'm still in the development phase of the site it's no problem to migrate to a node, but how do I link the node content to the specific users?
Jan